# MS Access to SQL data flow and performance

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, database-connection

I'm looking for some enlightenment here, can anyone tell me what actually happens when you use MS Access to query against a table (on MS SQL Server) linked via ODBC?  I mean in a regular linked style, not an Access ADP.

Does the ODBC driver somehow take the query from Access and perform a translation and let MSSQL do the heavy lifting or does ODBC merely facilitate the exchange of data down, then Access does work, then data goes back up?

I believe that to be the case although I can never seem to find a definitive answer.  And that it's in contrast to something like sending commands using ADO in Access to send/perform only the necessary task without pulling down all records.

I could very well be far far into the weeds on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC driver knows how to translate between Access and SQL Server SQL dialects and data types.

So, yes it *can* allow the server to do the "heavy lifting".  But your query must also be written properly to allow that to happen.

One type of problem would be a query with an Access-only function (which doesn't have a TSQL equivalent) in its `WHERE` clause.  In a case like that, Access would have to pull down every row from the server so that it could evaluate the function's result.

Comment: So say you're querying records on a date. Access query designer accepts where `mydatefield = #12/1/2012#` whereas T-SQL wants something like `mydatefield = '12/1/2012'`.

Also I assume anything that has to link to a local to Access table will need to pull down all records to evaluate, even with criteria for the ODBC SQL dataset?

Comment: Write the Access query with Access conventions for date literals (#12/1/2012#).  The driver translates that as an ODBC request for the server's dialect.  As a simplistic and exaggerated statement ... you, the developer, wouldn't need to know anything about how T-SQL deals with dates.  As a side point, I prefer date literals in #yyyy-mm-dd# format to limit any chance of confusion over #mm-dd-yyyy# vs. #dd-mm-yyyy#.

Comment: I think you're correct that joining a local Access table with a server table will likely force Access to pull down all the server candidate rows.